# Why does ReadDir not implement Clone?

Tags: rust, iterator, clone, readdir

I need to do several passes on a file directory for various reasons, in a fashion like:

```rust
fn foo(one_dir: ReadDir, another_dir: ReadDir) {
 // One pass..
 for d in one_dir.chain(another_dir) {
   // ..
 }

 // The second pass..
 for d in another_dir {
   // ..
 }
}
```

Since ReadDir doesn't implement Clone, the only workaround I have for this is to `collect` the `DirEntry`s in a `Vec` and chain the `Vec`s instead. This is a hacky solution and unnecessarily requires me to allocate memory which wouldn't have been needed if I could clone the original iterator.

Am I missing a crucial method/API that would allow me to do this or is there some other workaround?

Comment: A ReadDir is an iterator. Cloning it would clone the iteration state too, so it wouldn't help you.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Can I not clone the iterator before iterating on it?

Comment: `ReadDir` relies on some OS-specific primitives (e.g. [`readdir`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir)) that may not allow multiple iterations. (Plus of course the dir contents may change between the iterations, so there can't be any guarantee that they both would return the same sequence).

Comment: If you need the exact same list of entries in the second pass, there is no way around storing the list in a `Vec`. If you just want to iterate the same directory twice, you should accept a `P: AsRef<Path>` instead of a `ReadDir` and simply call `read_dir()` twice.

Comment: Since you're doing IO anyway, don't be afraid to allocate, it will only make you do _less_ syscalls and possibly make your program faster. Also, it eliminates the risk of the data changing in the meantime. Programming languages like Python only ever expose the "allocated" version, and no one cares. Sometimes Rust programmers are _too_ careful to avoid allocations.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Good idea.